# How to start writing a web log analyzer in Perl?

Tags: perl, apache, logging, analyzer

Taking information from a file that outputs entry after entry in this format:
IPAddress x x [date:time -x] "method url httpversion" statuscode bytes "referer" "useragent"

How would you go about accessing that file as a command-line argument and storing that information so that you could arrange it alphabetically by the IP addresses while keeping all of the information together? I assume I would need to use hashes and arrays somehow.

You could theoretically have as many text files as you want as command-line arguments but so far I haven't gotten that part to work, I just have:

```
./logprocess.pl monster.log #monster.log is the file that contains entries
```

then in the code, assume all variables not specified have been declared as scalars

```
my $x = 0;
my @hashstuff;
my $importPage = $ARGV[0];
my @pageFile = `$importPage`;
foreach my $line (@pageFile)
{

    $ipaddy, $date, $time, $method, $url, $httpvers, $statuscode, $bytes, $referer, $useragent =~ m#(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+) \S+ \S+ [(\d+/\S+/\d+):(\d+:\d+:\d+) \S+] "(\S+) (\S+) (\S+)" (\d+) (\d+) "(\S+)" "(\S+ \S+ \S+ \S+ \S+)"#
    %info = ('ipaddy' => $ipaddy, 'date' => $date, 'time' => $time, 'method' => $method, 'url' => $url, 'httpvers' => $httpvers, 'statuscode' => $statuscode, 'bytes' => $bytes, 'referer' => $referer, 'useragent' => $useragent);
    $hashstuff[$x] = %info;
    $x++;
}
```

There is definitely a better way to do this, as my compiler says I have global symbol errors like:

> Ambiguous use of % resolved as operator % at ./logprocess.pl line 51 (#2)
>   (W ambiguous)(S) You said something that may not be interpreted the way
>   you thought.  Normally it's pretty easy to disambiguate it by supplying
>   a missing quote, operator, parenthesis pair or declaration.

and it won't execute. I can't use any modules.

Comment: Are you aware that line 3 tells Perl to execute the `monster.log` command and fill `@pageFile` with the lines of its output?  Just use `while (<>)` to read all lines of all argumnets whenever you can.  Are you aware that every Perl script must start with `use strict; use warnings;` ?

Answer (score 4):

If the log is produced by Apache, you could utilize [Apache::ParseLog](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache%3a%3aParseLog) module. Look at examples at the end of the page for inspiration.

Regarding the error you mention, you should declare your array with `my`:

```
my @hashstuff;
```

and adding there a references. Also single item is accessed with `$hashstuff[$x]` (note the dollar at the beginning):

```
$hashstuff[$x] = { %info };
```

or you can get rid of `$x` completely:

```
push @hashstuff, { %info };
```